# How to find out if a class has been instantiated

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I usually use if(object!=null) but it doesn't work well.

How can I verify if the class is instantiated. I want to get rid of the 'cannot access a property of a null object or reference'.

Thanks!

I mean, the 'var object:Object;' is just a reference to an Object class instance. When i initialize it with 'object = new Object()' it runs the code in the constructor, initializing it. How can I check if it has been initialized or not.

Comment: Can you show an example where `if (object != null)` fails? It's hard to see how else you'd be able to tell if it has a non-null reference. Or do you mean initialised - like all properties have been set?

Comment: can you post in what consist you initialization ?

Comment: What initialized means depends on the type of object. I assume you're referring to a visual object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to know if the class has been initialized then I would recommend you use a getter inside the class that returns a true value when you have completed your initialization. Of course this only works if you have created an instance of the class. If I am not sure if the instance exists I first check if the instance is created. I have never had any problems with it.

```
if(myObject && myObject.isInitialized)
{
    // success
}
```

Comment: also, since you bring up mulitple conditionals, for code optimization, you should always put for least CPU intense check first in the conditional. i know it sounds nit picky, but while your are on the topic of multiple conditionals, i figured i'd mention it :)... ps, i was gonna add this comment to your article but the submission button didnt seem to work :/

Comment: gthmb: Thanks for the comment. I am not sure I understand it though. I am guessing you mean that I should not use multiple conditions by default because it takes more CPU to calculate. I am aware of that and therefore I only use it when I am not sure if the variable is set. 

I will look into the Wordpress comment bug. Thanks.

Comment: gthmb: In this case you definitely want myObject first since the following  conditional would throw a null pointer exception if not checked first.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `if(myobj!=null)`, you can just do `if(myobj)`.

checking to see if an instance or property is `null` is different than checking if it exists.

```
if(myobj)
```

will fail if `myobj` is `null` or `undefined` whereas `if(myobj!=null)` misses `undefined` (which is what the instance reference would be if it has never been assigned a value).

note: the `if(myobj)` will also be false if the value is set to `false` or `0`. since you are checking worried about a null pointer exception (therefore using a complex object), you can rule out `false` and `0` from being viable values (giving you a false negative) and use the more general if statement to check whether or not the instance exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a common situation where you start loading some assets in the constructor, let's suppose a background image.
This code would not work properly:

```
var object:TestObject = new TestObject(); //inside the contructor, the background image will start loading
object.background.width = 120; // this will not work, because the background is not loaded yet
```

There are a lot of ways to solve this...

You could load the assets before creating the object, and after they are loaded completely send them to the constructor as parameters.

Or you could define some properties inside the object which will be assigned to the loaded assets when they complete loading, something like this:

```
//outside
object.BackgroundWidth = 120;

----------

//inside the class
public var BackgroundWidth:int;
private var background:Bitmap;

public function TestObject(){
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, assignProperties);
    loader.load("img.png");
}
//this will make sure the width is applied to the background 
//when it's loaded completely
private function assignProperties(e:Event){
    background = Bitmap((event.currentTarget as LoaderInfo).content);
    background.width = BackgroundWidth; 
}
```

I hope this helped.